# How to quit a rebase but not check out the original branch?

Tags: git

Description for the `--abort` option of `git rebase` reads:

> abort and *check out the original branch*

**How do one abort a rebase *without* checking out the *original* branch?** (The "original" branch here is actually the subject branch specified for rebase.)

A typical use-case:

1. I start with `master` checked out:

   ```
   o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o (HEAD, master)
        \
         o---A
   ```
2. I type `git rebase master A` to rebase `A` onto `master`.
3. I either get heaps of conflicts, or run out of time to work, and decide I want to put `A` back and leave this for another day.
4. In essence, I want to abort and go back to where I was (i.e. `master`).  However, I want to do this without the intermediate step of getting dumped at `A`, because it's extremely far away, lots of files have changed, and I don't want to have to restart or otherwise do something to IDEs and other tools whose auto-refresh and auto-build features do all kinds of unpleasant things.

Comment: I think you might be misreading -- `abort` checks out the "original" branch, not "origin".  So you will return to your master branch after aborting.

Comment: @user2045006 Documentation of the `--abort` option reads "*If* `<branch>` *was provided when the rebase operation was started, then* `HEAD` *will be reset to* `<branch>`."

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no good way to do that. You can only `rm -rf .git/rebase-merge && git checkout -f master`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  You can only `git rebase --abort`, which will leave `HEAD` set to point to branch `A`, with `A` pointing to the same old tip commit as before.  This is because `git rebase` starts by, in effect, doing a `git checkout A` before it actually starts the real rebase process, and then forgets that you were ever anywhere else.

Moreover, this:

> In essence, I want to abort and go back to where I was (i.e. `master`). However, I want to do this without the intermediate step of getting dumped at `A`, because it's extremely far away, lots of files have changed, and I don't want to have to restart or otherwise do something to IDEs and other tools whose auto-refresh and auto-build features do all kinds of unpleasant things.

... is unfortunately already totally blown out of the water, because `git rebase` works *by* checking out other branches and commits.  (It used to literally check out the branch-name argument you gave it, though now it's a bit more complicated.)  The rebase process works by detaching your HEAD at the `--onto` target (which is the *upstream* if you did not give an `--onto`), then in effect doing a series of `git cherry-pick` operations for each commit that is to be copied.

Every step stomps quite heavily on both your work-tree and your index, since checkout, cherry-pick, and the merge mechanisms all use those.  This means that whether or not the rebase completes, your work-tree and index are potentially completely different from the way they were when you started.

Given that the goal is to defeat the IDE's bad behavior, the trick to make this work is to do the rebase in a separate work-tree.  The separate work-tree is (obviously) separate from the IDE's work-tree, and also has its own separate index.  Whether or not the rebase works, your IDE will be blissfully unaware of it, and hence undisturbed by it.

To get the separate work-tree you can use `git worktree add` if your Git version is new enough, or just work in a separate clone (a local clone will share most repository data through hard-links if possible).

Comment: Are you sure about `git checkout A`?  Every time I use it, `git rebase` starts by doing `git checkout <upstream>`, which is `master` for `git rebase master A`.  Or the `--onto` commit if I've specified that.  It's practically a no-op if I'm already on master.  Whichever the case, the working tree never goes in the vicinity of `A`, until I `--abort`.

Comment: @antak: that's why I said "in effect": the effect is *as if* you, yourself, ran `git checkout A` separately, and only then started the rebase by doing `git checkout --detach <upstream>` and doing the rest of the work. Git remembers the place to return to (after finishing or aborting) as "set HEAD to `A`".  (Long ago, before the scripts were fancied up some for efficiency, it actually did that `git checkout`, as I recall.)

Comment: Okay, part of the confusion appears to be that I'm thinking of `A` being a *commit* representing the position in the question, while you're talking about `A` as a branch name.  Even then, there's really no reason for rebase to checkout either commit or branch `A` on failure (e.g. on `--abort`), especially when I didn't start out on branch `A`.  That and how it was historically is just circumstantial.  I like your suggestion for using a disposable working tree, but the premise of your first two paragraphs is just one possible way of looking at it, and not entirely true in practice.

Comment: Ah, well, the problem is that `git checkout` (which `git rebase` does have to do, as it goes along) writes to *both* your current branch *and* your current commit, which means it treats arguments as both. That's yet another implementation detail that Git lets bleed through to user experience, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as at Git version 2.11, [`rebase` doesn't have](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase/2.11.0#_options) an option similar to [`cherry-pick --quit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#_sequencer_subcommands) for stopping right then and there.

One can do this manually however:

```
$ rm -r .git/rebase-apply

$ git checkout -f
```

The `rm -r .git/rebase-apply` is for making git forget that it's in the middle of a rebase.  This is required or wackiness will ensue, such as not being able to start a new rebase.  This directory is actually documented in the [git-rebase documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase/2.11.0#_description) as the path that `git rebase --abort` removes:

> To check out the original  and remove the .git/rebase-apply working files, use the command `git rebase --abort` instead.

<sup>We can't do as advised here because not "checkout the original" is the whole point of the question.</sup>

The `git checkout -f` is for resetting the working tree and index. (i.e. Getting rid of any dirty files.)  The `<branch>` parameter for `checkout` can be specified here if one wants to jump somewhere else rather than stay where rebase was stopped.